# Sending an ical file as an attachment with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code used to work (~March, 2018), but no longer does. Am I doing something wrong or does anyone know of a change with this?

```
function sendICAL(){
  var icalURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics";
  var icalBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(icalURL).getBlob();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("derekantrican@gmail.com", "ICAL file", "", {attachments: [icalBlob]});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using GmailApp use MailApp. They changed it.

```
MailApp.sendEmail("SomeEmail@email.com", "Some Subject"),'' ,{someVar})
```

Comment: Ok, simply changing `GmailApp` to `MailApp` fixed it. Thanks! Do you have a link for any sort of announcement that they changed it? Weird that other attachments work with `GmailApp` just not this

Comment: The only thing I can tell you for certain is it happened whenever they got rid of the legacy system and moved over to the new system. I believe GmailApp works for some things but GmailApp is generally used for mobile programming so there are certain limitations on it.